# Magento 2 How to make status disable when create new products

Tags: magento2, product, default, new-products

While creating new product in admin of magento 2.
Product status is enable.

How can i change that status to disable as by default at a time of create new product?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of research, I found solution:

Create а plugin for the class that is responsible for the status switch output on the product page.

> Module_Root/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General">
    <plugin name="setStatusForNewProducts"
            type="Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General"
    />
</type>
```

> Module_Root/Plugin/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php

```
<?php

namespace Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;

class General
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface $locator
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General $subject
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterModifyData(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General $subject,
        array $data
    ) {
        $modelId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        if(!$modelId) {
            $data[$modelId][$subject::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT][ProductAttributeInterface::CODE_STATUS] = '0';
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

I hope it'll help. Write me if you have any issues.